# Trying to setup a C programming environment

Tags: c++, c, windows, netbeans, codeblocks

I'm gonna start to learn C programming, and I've tried unsuccessfully to setup the environment.

I have Windows 8.1 64Bit. What I have tried is:

- Install the C/C++ plugin for my Netbeans IDE (which I currently use for Web Development)
- Install MinGW and add some other stuff according to [this documentation](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html)
- Netbeans seemed to work and build the hello world application, but in the end, the console froze and no hello world was displayed, it just stayed there thinking.

Then I decided to uninstall the C plugin for Netbeans and delete the MinGW folder to try Code::Blocks

After installing Code::Blocks with the default values and compilers, the same happens, it Build successfully but when the console opens it doesn't display any Hello World, it just freezes there!

It's really frustrating and I have no experience setting up environments for these languages.

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Why are you jumping through all those hoops? Just download free MS Visual Studio and start playing. Should be good enough for you. You can start exploring compiler differencies later.

Comment: If you use Avast anti-virus, it has lately been known to eat your program.

Comment: @SergeyA: Maybe OP wants a C standard-compliant compiler and one which is also available for other platforms?

Comment: There might be a very different problem on your system which is not related to the dev-tools.

Comment: @Olaf, judging by the choices OP has made, it does not seem this way. I believe, OP just wants to do some hellowording - you do not need latest clang for this.

Comment: @BoPersson ok The actuall reason was that Avast was keeping my program from executing, if you can put it as an answer I can mark it!
For the rest, all the dev tools and compilers are well installed and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Bo Persson for his quick comment.
If your program builds properly, but it freezes the console or just doesn't seem to start (but the IDE shows something's going on) is because AVAST Antivirus is stopping it from executing properly.

Just disable AVAST Shields while you're developing in C. I don't know if it applies to all versions of Windows or environments.